# ion-item with flow chart icon

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

could someone tell me how to make flow chart(the red circle part) on below picture.
[image]

I use code as below to make the rest part.

```html
<ion-item>
   <img item-start src="./assets/imgs/ico_note.png">
   <ion-label stacked>xxx</ion-label>
   <ion-input></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: you can use customised timeline view

Comment: could you please be more specific?

Comment: like this https://market.ionicframework.com/plugins/ionic-timeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      <div style="position: absolute;">
         <img style="height: 120px;margin-left: 20px;margin-top:25px;" src="./assets/imgs/xxx.png">
      </div>

      <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label style="font-size: 18px;color: gray;" stacked>xxx</ion-label>
            <ion-label style="font-size: 18px;">xxx</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label style="font-size: 18px;color: gray;" stacked>xxx</ion-label>
            <ion-label style="font-size: 18px;">xxx</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
      </div>
```